# Network Projections for Election Results

Tags: hypothesis-testing, predictive-models

What statistical process (or processes) do networks like FOX or NBC use to make projections based off election results? It has always interested me, since they have an amazing degree of accuracy. However, I have never heard a full explanation.

Comment: What sort of "projections based off election results" do you mean?  Do you mean post-election analyses of likely actions a newly-elected politician will take?  Or financial projections based off of political regime changes?

Comment: No, I mean when, on election night, NBC News projects that the Republican or Democratic candidate will win even before all the votes are counted.

Comment: Ah.  See, your use of the phrase "projections based off election results" implies that they are performing a forecasting analysis using the election results as the input.  I would suggest using verbiage like "What statistical processes do networks like FOX and NBC use to make election projections/forecasts?"